# spacing and alignment using array in a table with tabular setup

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Would someone please be willing to help me center the the contents of my table?
For some reason my text is being shifted to the bottom of each cell and the middle and far right vertical lines are not fully closed.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\begin{center}
\caption{\small{Example}\label{table:1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\\
$1$ & $2$ & $3$\\
\hline\\
$\{x, y, z\}$&
{\includegraphics[height=1.7 cm]{1}}&
$\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
\end{array}$\\
\hline\\
$\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$&
{\includegraphics[height=1.7 cm]{2}}&
$\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
\end{array}$\\
\hline\\
$\{5, 6, 7\}$&
{\includegraphics[height=1.7 cm]{3}}&
$\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide code which can be copied and not its image.

Comment: Would you be so nice as to post a full compilable `code`, not an `image`, so people who want to help don't have to type everything?

Comment: for the vertical lines note `\hline\\ ` makes a row with just an emoty cell in the first column, you want `\hline`   baseline of the image is its bottom edge so the text aligns with that.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you! I tried to do \hline alone but then the lines bleed into the images. it seems as though i need ot put the extra \\ after in order to make the cell large enough to fit the graphics :/

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

First I clean-up your code all unnecessary `\\` (after `\hline`) and surplus backslashes. The by help of packages `makecell` replace nested arrays, package `adjustbox` centered images in cell and also ad vertical margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\small
\centering
\caption{Example}
    \label{table:1}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
    \hline
1               &   2   &   3           \\
    \hline
\{x, y, z\}     &   \includegraphics[height=1.7cm, margin=0pt 3pt, valign=M]{example-image-a}
                    &   \makecell{
                        1\\
                        2\\
                        3\\
                        4}              \\
    \hline
\{1, 2, 3, 4\}  &   \includegraphics[height=1.7cm, margin=0pt 3pt, valign=M]{example-image-b}
                    &   \begin{array}{c}% to see that between use of array and makecell is not difference
                        1\\
                        2\\
                        3
                        \end{array}     \\
    \hline
\{5, 6, 7\}     &   \includegraphics[height=1.7cm, margin=0pt 3pt, valign=M]{example-image-c}
                    &   \{1, 2, 3, 4\}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much! unfortunately, I am forced to use the array setup because my employer insists on using it in this table. Is it possible to get things properly aligned while using array? I'd rather not use it and have been able to get things aligned using multirow instead but the boss lady insists on using array as part of a "better construction" :/

Comment: Try with array and see, that in the in the result is no difference. It is only with more simple code with `makecell` , which internally use `array` ...

Comment: hi Zarko, thank you so much for all your help. i tried the setup but i get an undefined errpr at:

Comment: hi Zarko, thank you so much for all your help. i tried the setup but i get an undefined error at: \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}. Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, but i can't see your setup (my crystal ball take a free weekend :-) ). MWE, which I provide in my answer works (also with nested array) without any error, warning or bad boxes. More I can say, if you provide in question (by edit it)  complete small document, which start wit `\documentclass{...}` , used packages  `\begin{document}` your code for table  and end with `\end{document}`, maybe I will be able to see a source of your problem.